# Combining QR Codes with Geo Location

Tags: geocaching, qr

We are planing a geo caching game, where we want to use QR Codes. Each time a player scans a QR Code, he will be redirect to a specific landing page.

To each QR Code we want to add geo information like an address or lng/lat. So we can find out, where and how often the QR Codes have been scanned, without asking the mobile device to send its location to us. Is there a service, that provides tagging a QR Code with a geo location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at http://qrd.by. It looks like a service that could cover your needs. They provide geotagging services combined with qr codes under http://qrd.by/geotag/create.

Comment: Wow, those where quick answers. qrd.by looks promising, i'll check out their API.

Answer (score 2):

I found this online utility - [QR Code Geographic Generator](http://blog.qr4.nl/QR-Code-Geographic.aspx)

According to the site you can

> Use the geographic QR code generator to create QR codes with your
>   embedded co-ordinates. The geographic co-ordinates are stored and when
>   scanned will redirect to a static mobile google map of your location.
>
> Either enter your latitude and logitude co-ordinates, type in an
>   address, or place a marker on the map below. Click the 'Create Map QR
>   Code' button to generate the geographic QR code.

Comment: Thx! That's a good idea, but we want the users to be redirected to a specific landing page and not to a google map. The QR Code should have an URL and geo location in it encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Just create Text QR Code like this:

```
geo:20.33470,20.39448
```

DD.DDDDDD - latitude and logitude format

[image]

Somewere in Africa

Text QR Code https://zxing.appspot.com/generator
[image: Text QR Code]

**Apps for iOS**

- Create QR Code [Qrafter - QR Code Reader and Generator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qrafter-qr-code-reader-and-generator/id416098700?mt=8)
- Scan QR Code [Quick Scan - QR Code Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-scan-qr-code-reader/id483336864?mt=8)

Comment: Please expand on your answer a bit--what software are you using?

Comment: Hi, you may use any online qr generator, https://zxing.appspot.com/generator or https://www.unitag.io/qrcode

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this QR Code Generator: https://qrplanet.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.sitedetour.com/features/dynamic-qr-code-generator

Its prefect for this use case. They have an extremely powerful Personalization Audience Builder. You can target based on location, language, device and a lot more. You can even combine multiple audiences together for very complex use cases.